# Mutate multiple variables based on a given condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
  library(dplyr)

     d <- data_frame(
      region = c('all', 'nj', 'rkl', 'all'),
      figures= c(5, 7, 4, 8),
      figures2 = c(3, 5, 6, 7))
```

I would like to use dplyr to say when 'region' = 'all' then turn 'figures' and 'figures2' to 'x'. I don't want to use mutate to create new variables, I want to change the values in the variables that already exist. So the data would look like this:

```
  d2 <- data_frame(
          region = c('all', 'nj', 'rkl', 'all'),
          figures= c(x, 7, 4, x),
          figures2 = c(x, 5, 6, x))
```

I think I need something like this:

```
 d %>% mutate_at(vars(1:3), funs(ifelse(region = 'all', 'x', .)))
```

However, this doesn't quite work.

Comment: `d %>% mutate_at(vars(2:3), list(~ ifelse(region == 'all', 'x', .)))` haven't tested but try

Comment: Any reason why you’re not performing two `mutate`s? One for `figures` and one for `figures2`? If you have many more such columns consider `gather`ing your columns into long format.

Comment: you're right - I just did that before you posted and it worked. I'll delete the post as  this question is answered else where. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were on the right path with `mutate_at`:

```
d %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(2:3), list(~ ifelse(region == 'all', 'x', .)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  region figures figures2
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   
1 all    x       x       
2 nj     7       5       
3 rkl    4       6       
4 all    x       x
```

You can just replace `'x'` with a number if needed.

**EDIT**.

- I also think that `replace` is a better alternative, you could just do `d %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(2:3), list(~ replace(., region == 'all', 'x')))` as well;
- Moreover, as noted by @Moody_Mudskipper, no need for `list` with newest `dplyr` version, so `mutate_at(2:3, ~ ifelse(region == 'all', 'x', .))` would do the job as well.

Comment: With the last version of dplyr There's no need for you to wrap your formula into a list to access other columns in `mutate_at`. There is also no need to use `vars` with numeric indices. So this is fine : `d %>% mutate_at(2:3, ~ ifelse(region == 'all', 'x', .))`

Comment: Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper, didn't know about that - will modify it!

Answer (score 4):

One way with `mutate` and `replace`:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(figures = replace(figures, region == 'all', 10)) %>%
  mutate(figures2 = replace(figures2, region == 'all', 10))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  region figures figures2
  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 all         10       10
2 nj           7        5
3 rkl          4        6
4 all         10       10
```

I am using 10 here as your x

Comment: Yeah this is good as well, gives a bit more control if you want to replace different columns with different values

Answer (score 4):

An option would be be also to use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~ case_when(region == "all" ~ 'x',
                                         TRUE ~ as.character(.) )))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  region figures figures2
#  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   
#1 all    x       x       
#2 nj     7       5       
#3 rkl    4       6       
#4 all    x       x
```

---

A `base R` compact option would be

```
d[d$region == "all", -1] <- "x"
```